# Show only one part of data into listview and get all values in new activity android studio?

Tags: android, json, listview

I have a question.
I'm new to android studio and tryed a lot of different things for testing.
Now i have made a little program where i can click a button and it starts a new activity with a listview that shows me some data from a mysql extracted from json data.

I have it so far that when you click a product in the listview it opens as test a new activity with textview and shows the data that a past from the listview.

My problem is the following.

I want to load all the data from selected line in listview and show that data in the new activity.

But how must i do that?

The code part that i have for the loadintolistview is this.:

```
    private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    String[] stocks = new String[jsonArray.length()];
    //String[] stockstot = new String[jsonArray.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        stocks[i] = obj.getString("DatumTot") + " " +  obj.getString("Product")+ " " + obj.getString("Prod_Nr")+ " " + obj.getString("Batch_Nr")+ " " + obj.getString("Orders")+ " " + obj.getString("Lijn")+ " " + obj.getString("FP");
        //stockstot[i] = obj.getString("DatumTot") + " " +obj.getString("Product")+ " " +obj.getString("Prod_Nr")+ " " +obj.getString("Batch_Nr")+ " " +obj.getString("Orders")+ " " +obj.getString("Lijn")+ " " +obj.getString("FP")+ " " +obj.getString("PeroxideType")+ " " +obj.getString("PeroxideProcent")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeA")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeSiloA")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeB")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeSiloB")+ " " +obj.getString("AggloProcent")+ " " +obj.getString("AggloSilo")+ " " +obj.getString("RecycleProcent")+ " " +obj.getString("RecycleSilo")+ " " +obj.getString("MVRml10ml")+ " " +obj.getString("MVRSTD")+ " " +obj.getString("MFRg10ml")+ " " +obj.getString("AshProcent")+ " " +obj.getString("VochtProcent")+ " " +obj.getString("KleurL")+ " " +obj.getString("KleurA")+ " " +obj.getString("KleurB")+ " " +obj.getString("Operator1")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeType1")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeType2")+ " " +obj.getString("Productielijn1")+ " " +obj.getString("Productielijn2")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeBatchNr1")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeBatchNr2")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeVochtProcent1")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeVochtProcent2")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeKleurL1")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeKleurL2")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeKleurA1")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeKleurA2")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeKleurB1")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeKleurB2")+ " " +obj.getString("Remark1")+ " " +obj.getString("Remark2")+ " " +obj.getString("Remark3")+ " " +obj.getString("MeltDens")+ " " +obj.getString("Reg_sample");

    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stocks);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selectedItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            //Create the bundle
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            //Add your data to bundle
            bundle.putString("stuff", selectedItem);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//display the text of button1
            Intent appInfo = new Intent(Extrusie1Activity.this, Extrusion1infoActivity.class);

            //Add the bundle to the intent
            appInfo.putExtras(bundle);

            startActivity(appInfo);
        }
    });

}
```

As you can see , the part with String[] stockstot is all the data that i want to see in the new activity.
Is there someone who can help me?

Comment: Enable your commented codes for **String[] stockstot** and inside onItemClick, change `String selectedItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);` to `String selectedItem = stockstot[position];` Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click an item you already accessed the string, just pass it via intent to the next activity like this:

**update**

**do this:**

```
 ..........
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
 //add this
 List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
 String[] stocks = new String[jsonArray.length()];
```

**the loop**

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    stocks[i] = obj.getString("DatumTot") + " " +  obj.getString("Product")+ " " + obj.getString("Prod_Nr")+ " " + obj.getString("Batch_Nr")+ " " + obj.getString("Orders")+ " " + obj.getString("Lijn")+ " " + obj.getString("FP");


    String full = obj.getString("DatumTot") + " " +obj.getString("Product")+ " " +obj.getString("Prod_Nr")+ " " +obj.getString("Batch_Nr")+ " " +obj.getString("Orders")+ " " +obj.getString("Lijn")+ " " +obj.getString("FP")+ " " +obj.getString("PeroxideType")+ " " +obj.getString("PeroxideProcent")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeA")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeSiloA")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeB")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeSiloB")+ " " +obj.getString("AggloProcent")+ " " +obj.getString("AggloSilo")+ " " +obj.getString("RecycleProcent")+ " " +obj.getString("RecycleSilo")+ " " +obj.getString("MVRml10ml")+ " " +obj.getString("MVRSTD")+ " " +obj.getString("MFRg10ml")+ " " +obj.getString("AshProcent")+ " " +obj.getString("VochtProcent")+ " " +obj.getString("KleurL")+ " " +obj.getString("KleurA")+ " " +obj.getString("KleurB")+ " " +obj.getString("Operator1")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeType1")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeType2")+ " " +obj.getString("Productielijn1")+ " " +obj.getString("Productielijn2")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeBatchNr1")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeBatchNr2")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeVochtProcent1")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeVochtProcent2")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeKleurL1")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeKleurL2")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeKleurA1")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeKleurA2")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeKleurB1")+ " " +obj.getString("FlakeKleurB2")+ " " +obj.getString("Remark1")+ " " +obj.getString("Remark2")+ " " +obj.getString("Remark3")+ " " +obj.getString("MeltDens")+ " " +obj.getString("Reg_sample");

   //add to list

   items.add(full);

}
```

**click item:**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String selectedItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        //get the full item to pass

        String fullItem = items.get(postion);

        Intent appInfo = new Intent(Extrusie1Activity.this, Extrusion1infoActivity.class);

        appInfo.putExtra("data",fullItem);

        startActivity(appInfo);
    }
});
```

In the `Extrusion1infoActivity` activity in on create():

```
String dataToShow = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
```

Comment: But that is not all my data if you look at //stockstot[i] part. If i load all that, then its to mutch for the listview. I just want to some parts of the json file in my listview and if i click on it then i want to see all the data of the clicked item

Comment: Thank you so mutch, it works, just how i like it :)

Comment: 1 question , is it also possible to split the JSON file so i can use the values into a array list? maybe also global over that screen?